# How to set log rotate for an application for compressing and rotating at interval of 5 days?

Tags: compression, logrotate

I am facing the problem in doing the settings in

```
     logrotate.conf
```

I had done the settings once, but it didn't work accordingly.

The main condition is to rotate the log files along with compression at the interval of 5 days

```
 /var/log/humble/access.log
     { 

        daily
        copytruncate
        rotate 5
         create 755 humble humble
         dateext
         compress
         include /etc/logrotate.d/humble/
    }
```

Even after doing this, compression was stopped after days.

Comment: You should give some more information, and some examples of what you have tried.
You did not mentioned the system or server you are using.
For example, i use a shell script in the linux crontab to compress the logs a remove old ones, please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: the changes i had done please go through once ... and please help me to resolve

Answer (score 0):

Your logrotate.conf file should have mention to include your file "humble":-

include `/etc/logrotate.d/humble`

#End of Logrotate.conf

and then in your /etc/logrotate.d/humble

```
/var/log/humble/access.log
 { 

    daily
    copytruncate
    rotate 5
    create 755 humble humble
    dateext
    compress

}
```

The number specified after `rotate` gives how many files to be kept for backup after rotation. Here it is 5.

Also, you need to add a rule in the crontab file for triggering the logrotate every 5 days.

Rule in crontab file for running it every 5 days is :-

```
0 0 */5 * *
```

Comment: actually the  main problem was ,the rotation continues but the compression was stopped  ..

Comment: and please tell the path ... that should be written along with the  .. do i need any parser .... or just                                             0 0 */5 * * /etc/logrotate.conf